# Java - Values being changed suddenly and print line statement running twice?

Tags: java

I have the following code block:

```
    } else {
        System.out.println("call");
        int left = solveExpression(leftExpression.toString(), enviornment);
        int right = solveExpression(rightExpression.toString(), enviornment);
        System.out.println(left + "  " + right);
        return left % right;
    }
```

The output of the code is exactly as follows:

call

10  2

12  0

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at PrefixSolver.getOperatorExpression(PrefixSolver.java:245)
at PrefixSolver.solveExpression(PrefixSolver.java:83)
at PrefixSolver.parseDefinition(PrefixSolver.java:168)
at PrefixSolver.parseEnviornment(PrefixSolver.java:122)
at PrefixSolver.solveExpression(PrefixSolver.java:55)
at PrefixSolver.parseDefinition(PrefixSolver.java:168)
at PrefixSolver.parseEnviornment(PrefixSolver.java:122)
at PrefixSolver.solveExpression(PrefixSolver.java:55)
at PrefixSolver.getOperatorExpression(PrefixSolver.java:232)
at PrefixSolver.solveExpression(PrefixSolver.java:83)
at PrefixSolver.parseDefinition(PrefixSolver.java:168)
at PrefixSolver.parseEnviornment(PrefixSolver.java:122)
at PrefixSolver.solveExpression(PrefixSolver.java:55)
at PrefixSolver.getOperatorExpression(PrefixSolver.java:232)
at PrefixSolver.solveExpression(PrefixSolver.java:83)
at PrefixSolver.solve(PrefixSolver.java:12)
at Prefix.main(Prefix.java:17)
```

I'm very confused how this is even possible. The first println is correct (10 2) but then it is changed somehow?? Just to see if somehow solveExpression is getting called again I put println's in the method and it is not getting called again. The values are just changing somehow..?

Comment: Run it with a debugger to see what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a recursive method call - as Henry said, go for debugging to see which calls are made and what params are passed